# what is the difference between MM and mm and why not have DD instead of dd for date-fns

Tags: date-fns

**See example code sandbox**
https://codesandbox.io/s/date-fns-v2-xjv04?file=/src/index.js

```
import { format } from "date-fns";
const strDate =  "2021-08-06T10:20:50.000Z";
const dt = new Date(strDate);
dt.toISOString(strDate)                    // 2021-08-06T10:20:50.000Z 
format(dt, "yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss.SSSxxx") // 2021-08-06T11:20:50.000+01:00 
format(dt, "dd-MM-yyyy")                   // 06-08-2021 
format(dt, "dd-mm-yyyy")                   // 06-20-2021 - WRONG MONTH 20 ??????
```

I am confused why there are variations in this? Also it's easy to make the mistake and use lowercase for everything since there isn't a DD and you begin with dd.

Comment: ok I realised the mm is actually minutes. But it would be easier to identify separation of date to time if date is all in uppercase. Also, I can't see any reason to have minutes immediately following dates, so it would be a good idea to provide a warning message to user if they make this mistake and put mm instead of MM immediately following a date

Comment: Practically every standard library (for any language) with datetime support and custom formatting strings uses these same conventions.

Comment: @Damien_The_Unbeliever oh interesting. Can you name a few?

Comment: Here's [.NETs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/base-types/custom-date-and-time-format-strings). [Java](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/text/SimpleDateFormat.html) (Note that these both do different things for `h` vs `H` and the latter also does assign meaning to `D`)

Comment: I see now:  D Day in year Number 189
d Day in month Number 10